# Creating a new table as select SQL statement in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am currently creating a new table that will add an existing column from another existing table. It seems there is some common mistake in my SQL statement which I do not know. Can someone help me?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data_versioning_nonull(new_table_name VARCHAR(100),column_name VARCHAR(100), current_table_name VARCHAR(100))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE ('CREATE TABLE ''' || quote_ident(new_table_name) || ' AS SELECT ' || quote_ident(column_name) || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(current_table_name));
END $$;

CALL data_versioning_nonull('sales_2019_nonull', 'orderid', 'sales_2019');
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'sales_2019_nonull AS SELECT orderid FROM sales_2019"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE 'sales_2019_nonull AS SELECT orderid FROM sales...
```

Comment: You have redundant quotes - `EXECUTE ('CREATE TABLE ' || ...`

Comment: Oh that's why haha. thank you!